# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException in Spark although driver/client has precisely same version as Server

Tags: scala, apache-spark

A task that works in spark local mode is not working for standalone cluster running on the same machine.

The only difference is:

```
local[*]
```

vs

```
spark://<host>.local:7077
```

for the master

I am able to run `spark pi` against the master at the above address and also use the `spark gui`: so the *master* address is generally working for spark.

Here is the (normal) spark init code:

```
 val sconf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName("EpisCatalog")
 val sc = new SparkContext(sconf)
```

Here is the stacktrace from running the program:

```
15/12/03 03:39:04.746 main WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/03 03:39:07.706 main WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
15/12/03 03:39:27.739 appclient-registration-retry-thread ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@b649f0b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5ef7a52b[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1.apply(AppClient.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1.apply(AppClient.scala:102)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.tryRegisterAllMasters(AppClient.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.org$apache$spark$deploy$client$AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$registerWithMaster(AppClient.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1130)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am running spark 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT. It has been "installed" to local maven repo and I have verified that the client is using the latest local maven repo version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It could be solved by using the full host url (can be found on the Master Web UI, port 18080) instead of just the hostname or localhost.
So I had to use mymachine.mycompany.org instead of mymachine

Comment: This was addressed in the OP: SparkPi is working using the fqdn and the same fqdn `machine.local` is used in the execution of this task. It is not a dns issue.

Comment: @yoooshi what full  host url you are refering ? i am running on "yarn" mode. I have not changed anything ..but i am getting this error in my spark job.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and in my case there was version mismatch. I had Spark Driver written on 1.5.1 version and Spark Cluster setup on 1.6.0.

Maybe you deploy cluster on stable version which was on that time 1.5.1.

Comment: my spark job coded with 2.4.3version, and  running 2.4.3version still i am getting this error ,any help plz